# I had created CassandraCluster on 3 nodes 1 node the bin/nodetool status and bin/cqlsh is working fine and other 2 nodes I got the errors listed below

Tags: clustering

nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.

Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:9042': ConnectionRefusedError(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})